# Click on page load to get a url

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The code below is supposed to get the new url as root while the page loads.  I tried targeting the class as .click and that didn't work as well.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").trigger('click');
    });
    </script>

    <a href="/" class="click">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: its recommended to accept ppl answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `trigger('click')` to trigger the JavaScript code for a click event. However, for security reasons, you cannot use it to simulate a mouse click that would actually open a link. You **must** do that by assigning to `window.location` directly:

```
$('a.click').trigger('click'); // everything but changing the URL
window.location = $('a.click').attr('href'); // change the URL
```

Also, [please read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: In this case you can use `DOMElement.href` to save a few CPU cycles: `window.location = $('a.click')[0].href;`.

Comment: @Jasper True, although from a developer standpoint it adds little value to sacrifice readability to spare a handful of cycles unless you're in a high-frequency loop. "Premature optimization" and all that.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use this and skip jQuery and the a tag altogether:

```
<script>
    window.location.href = '/';
</script>
```

This will set the browser's address to the site root and take you there without having to simulate any clicks or even wait on document ready.  Also, no jQuery needed.

Comment: I tried that but I have an ajax thing that works when you click.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more?  Maybe you should explain in your post what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So I'm using jquery mobile, and trying to get the default link targeting via.. the documentation http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html